# Error obtaining readings from Arduino to Raspberry pi

Tags: sql, syntax, mariadb, mysql-connector

I have the following code trying to obtain temperature from an Arduino Uno connected to a Raspberry PI:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import serial

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='IOT', password='12345678', database='iotstorage')
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(buffered=True)


while 1:
    t = ser.readline()
    t = str(t)

    sql = "INSERT INTO example (temperature) VALUES (%s)" %(t)

    cursor.execute(sql)
    mariadb_connection.commit()
    cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
```

It gives me the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/pi/Desktop/procedure/sketch_dec03.py", line 25, in 
>       cursor.execute(sql)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 569, in execute
>       self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 553, in cmd_query
>       result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 442, in _handle_result
>       raise errors.get_exception(packet)
>   mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'b'5.19\r\n')' at line 1

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert a number, while the value from the serial device is not a number.

You can either

- add quotes in your SQL statement around parameter marker %s: `"INSERT INTO example (temperature) VALUES ('%s')" %(t)`
- or convert the value from serial device to a valid decimal number.

Some code comments:

- don't use mariadb as package module name, this might conflict with
  MariaDB Connector/Python
- create cursor once, not twice with different parameters
- do you really want to list all your databases
  after inserting a temperature value?!